# References invalid table in create table script with foreign keys

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a table in SQL Server with two foreign keys. But the problem is it's not recognizing one of the reference tables.

Here is table creation script.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmpGroup]
(
    [Id] INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY ,    
    [GroupId] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,     
    CONSTRAINT [GroupId_FK] 
       FOREIGN KEY([GroupId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Group](Id),  --Getting error on [dbo].[Group]
    [EmployeeId] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,      
    CONSTRAINT [EmployeeId_FK] 
       FOREIGN KEY([EmployeeId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Employee](Id)
)
GO
```

SQL Server is throwing the error on `[dbo].[Group]`. Here is the error message.

[image]

I have created both of the tables `[dbo].[Group]` and `[dbo].[Employee]`. And the confusion is, why it's not throwing the same error for `[dbo].[Employee]`?

**Edit**

Script of Group and Employee Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee](
    [Id] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,  -- we allow custom id addition, so no need of identity at all
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [RightThumb] [varbinary](max) NULL,
    [RightIndex] [varbinary](max) NULL,
    [LeftThumb] [varbinary](max) NULL,
    [LeftIndex] [varbinary](max) NULL,
    [CardNo] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [MayFairNo] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [UHFNo] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Face] [varbinary](max) NULL,
    -- face headers column? 
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Group](
    [Id] INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY ,    -- we allow custom id addition, so no need of identity at all
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,    
)
```

Comment: Plz, Check the Database name - Whether u had created the **Group** table in Right DB or not? if u didn't find out - Just share the same table script

Comment: Table exist in the same database

Comment: Plz, Share all the 3 tables Scripts

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full and complete text of the error message you're getting. If you're only concerned about the red squiggle under `[dbo].[Group]` it could just be that the IntelliSense cache in SSMS hasn't sensed a newly created table yet - press `Ctrl+Shift+R` to refresh it then wait a few seconds to see if it goes away.

Comment: Oh My, @AlwaysLearning I use Ctrl+Shift+R many times on a web pages but didn't aware of this refresh problem in SQL Server Query Editor. I restarted the SQL Server management Studio to refresh IntelliSense cache but that didn't work

Comment: @AlwaysLearning can you put your comment as an answer, so I can give you the due credit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only concerned about the red squiggle under `[dbo].[Group]` it could just be that the IntelliSense cache in SSMS hasn't sensed a newly created table yet - press `Ctrl+Shift+R` to refresh it then wait a few seconds to see if it goes away.